# Why is apache enforcing SSL (https)? How to undo this?

Tags: ssl, https, apache2, vhosts

We are running a multi-host apache2 environment for several years. Out of a sudden apache no seems to require https.

Some trivial websites are cofigured without certificates on port 80 (and with self signed or let's-encrypt certificates on port 443).

With the recent automatic renewal of a let's-encrypt certificate I got an error message related to problems to retrieve the acme-challenge via http.

[image: apache2 requires SLL]

It seems to be related to a recent change of the default configuration of apache2 under  Debian 4.19.x .

However I did not find any option in apache2 to undo the enforcement for SSL.

Here is my configuration for on of the respective vhost's (the problem exists also for another host):

```
<VirtualHost *:80 >

    ServerName www.antXXX.XX
    ServerAlias antXXX.XX *.antXXX.XX
    ServerAdmin webmaster@...

    DocumentRoot /data/www/htdocsantXXX

    ErrorDocument 503 /ausserBetrieb.html

    <Directory /data/www/htdocsantXXX>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            <RequireAll>
                    require all granted
            </RequireAll>

            RedirectMatch ^/$ /index.html
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/antXXX/errorantXXX.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/antXXX/accessantXXX.log combined

    ServerSignature On
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.antXXX.XX
        ServerAlias antXXX.XX *.antXXX.XX
        ServerAdmin webmaster@...

        DocumentRoot /data/www/htdocsantXXX
     ...
  </VirtualHost>
```

I was not able to find the respective option in the basic configuration of apache nor the error document that contains the HTML-Text for "This site is configured to require an SSL (https) connection...".

I know that there is the http-option `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1` . However the problem also exists, when retrieving the web document locally with  `curl -v http://www.antXXX.XX` .

How can I undo the https-requirement for the respective vhosts?

Thank you for you support

Wallenstein

Answer (score 0):

Oh sorry. Finally I have found the culprit.

I have recently experimented with the yubikey authorization in the module authn-yubikey .
Its activation seemed to enforce https. At least I found the respecitive HTML-code via the strings-command.

After disabling this module http-access was available again.

Wallenstein